# Get test coverage on lines that won't execute if Test.isRunningTest() is true

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I was trying to write a test class for one of my classes. It has a condition which checks for whether the run is a test run or not.

```
  try
    {
        if(!test.isrunningtest())
        {
            schId=system.schedule('CPRO Invoice Processor Optimized', dt.format('s m H d M ? yyyy'),new CPRO_InvProc());//started here
            //system.debug('The newly scheduled job id :'+ schid+' at the time of '+ datetime.now());  //just to make sure 
            string emailbody='The newly scheduled job id :'+ schid+' at the time of '+ datetime.now();        
            Workflow_email__C recCPRO1=new workflow_email__C(Email_Type__c='CPRO Jobs',Body__c=emailBody+'\nThanks\n\nCPRO Invoice Processor Optimized');
            insert recCPRO1; // this object will send the email alert based on workflow   
        }
    }
    catch(exception e){
        //system.debug('We got an exeception while scheduling new job and resp error message is '+e.getmessage()+' at the time of '+datetime.now());
        string emailbody='We got an exeception while scheduling new job and resp error message is '+e.getmessage()+' at the time of '+datetime.now();
        Workflow_email__C recCPRO2=new workflow_email__C(Email_Type__c='CPRO Jobs',Body__c=emailBody+'\nThanks\n\nCPRO Invoice Processor Optimized');
        insert recCPRO2; // this object will send the email alert based on workflow 
    }
```

Is it possible to write a test code which will cover lines inside the `if statement`.

Comment: Do you have a class called Test?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: @EricSSH I have not defined a call called Test. For this code, I am not getting an error. The code is within a function. And when I am calling this function from my test class, it runs successfully however it skips the line inside the if statement as `isrunningtest()` is true. So was wondering is there a way to explicitly set the value for `isrunningtest()` to `false` so that the code inside the if statement is also covered?

Comment: You don't have any code inside the if statement, throw a System.debug('Testing is running ' +Test.IsRunningTest()); I think that would work.. And see what it returns (Should be false)

Comment: @EricSSH Thanks!! Updated my question with the code. Yes, it is returning `false`. Thus I am not able to get code coverage for the lines inside the `if statement`. Is it possible to get code coverage on these lines as well?

Comment: why are you having deployment issues forcing you to exclude code from executing during a testmethod? Perhaps that is what needs to be addressed

Comment: That is caused by a managed package. But will start investigating that area too. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is in the Salesforce documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_test.htm

> isRunningTest()
>   Returns true if the currently executing code was called by code contained in a test method, false otherwise. Use this method if you need to run different code depending on whether it was being called from a test.

isRunningTest() will always return true if you are running a test, thus all the code within your if(!isRunningTest()) bracket is not going to run if you are running a test, ever. If you want to cover this code at all, you are going to have to modify the code to remove the if(!isRunningTest()) condition.

Answer (score -3):

You can put two lines from inside the test to out of test.

keep system schedule and insert record inside test and get other two lines out as they don't appear to be harmful regardless of the test running status.

set a default id and then when not running test, replace that id.

not a good solution but, meh :/